# Bootable USB 3.0 have frequent performance drops while using

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, performance

I created an bootable usb stick using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1tZ7X0U-8c&t=667s .
I got a completly new usb 3.0.
The installation took like 4-5 hours.
It installated without any errors.
However when i start the laptop with the bootable usb i firstly takes 20 minutes to start and secondly everything works really slow and droping in performance.
For example if i want to open firefox it takes 5-10 minutes for the message to appear that firefox is not reacting. Starting the terminal takes 1-2 minutes.
Then i opened "disk" to do a benchmark and got this output:
[image: output of benchmark]

I get frequently performance loses as you can see on the first half of the picture. It sometimes stabilising for a couple of minutes but then it loses performance again.

Kind regards,
TheGameIsNeverOver

Comment: Hello. What did you install? Are you trying to run an OS from a USB. Many more details required.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.